# How do I add a new button to the infowindow on the marker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

This JS code

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '
      </p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

I want to add a new button to the infowindow called 'uluru'. The button should be right next to the closing key like the photo.Can you help me??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a button by setting content with `contentString` and position it to the place you want like the following demo.

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">' + '<button type="button" class="custom_button">!!!</button>' +
    '<div id="siteNotice"></div>' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi)</p>' +
    `<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">` +
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
    '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

initMap()
```

```css
#map {
  height: 90vh;
}

.custom_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```